# How do you solve no matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 in mingw64?

Tags: kivy, mingw-w64, msys2, pygobject, pacman-package-manager

I am looking to make a small test app that uses python, pygobject, kivy, and gstreamer on windows 11.

Because of pygobject, I have to use a mingw64 terminal since it does not work directly on windows 11 or with a python version greater than 3.4 (using a [sourceforge installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/)).

In mingw64, I've been facing the issue of not being able to install kivy due to `No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3`

I've looked at this [thread](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8042) and tried the proposed solutions of using "the latest cutting edge Nightly wheels" with:

```
python -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/

python -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

However this gave the same error.

I also tried to download version 3.10 of mingw-w64-x86_64-python, with pacman and a zst folder, installed pip with `python -m ensurepip` and was still getting the same error with Kivy. I don't like this route because I will also [have to build all my python packages](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/discussions/18881#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20you%20can%20rebuild%20every%20python%20packages) due to the nature of mingw64's packages with pacman.

How can I get this setup to work? Is there a way to not install the gstreamer dependency for kivy since it is optional according to their [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip:%7E:text=gstreamer%20(optional))? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Kivy for Python 3.5+ on Windows only supports the MSVC compiler, and you can't mix mingw64 gcc Python with the python.org Windows version of Python compiled with MSVC.

[Gvsbuild](https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild) supports building GTK with PyGObject and Gstreamer with MSVC. You could then install Kivy normally, since all your dependencies would be built with MSVC.